# On maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

It states that

> If f is a non-constant holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$, then
> f cannot attain a maximum in $\Omega$

It seems that $\Omega$ being region is an important assumption, but with respect to what topological space is $\Omega$ open? Say, f is defined on an upper half-plane, obviously, it is not open in $\mathbb{C}$ but the upper half-plane is open with respect to itself, by the definition of topology. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open subset of the complex plane $\mathbb C$.  The point is that "holomorphic in $\Omega$" means "differentiable at every point of $\Omega$, and differentiability at a point $p$ involves a limit as $z \to p$, which is only defined if the domain $\Omega$ includes a neighbourhood of $p$.  A function defined on the (closed) upper half plane can't be holomorphic there because for points $p$ on the real line a limit as $z \to p$ would have to include points $z$ in the lower half plane, where the function is not defined.